# JSON Document is too large - snowflake stored procedure

Tags: javascript, json, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_return_table(COL_NAMES ARRAY)
  RETURNS VARIANT NOT NULL
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS
  $$
    // This variable will hold a JSON data structure that holds ONE row.
    var row_as_json = {};
    // This array will contain all the rows.
    var array_of_rows = [];
    // This variable will hold a JSON data structure that we can return as
    // a VARIANT.
    // This will contain ALL the rows in a single "value".
    var table_as_json = {};
    var driver_id;
    // Construct the column names as a comma-separated string
    var col_names_str = COL_NAMES.join(', ');
    // Run SQL statement(s) and get a resultSet.
    var command = "SELECT DISTINCT d.gid FROM NApp.CORE.DRIVER d LEFT JOIN napp.core.organisation o ON o.gid = d.organisation_id WHERE o.gid = '7703fd1a-c991-4505-98d4-d4b7b1c13da0' AND d.active = TRUE AND o.active = TRUE AND o.sf_inactive_date IS NULL AND d.sf_inactive_date IS NULL";
    var cmd1_dict = {sqlText: command};
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1_dict);
    var rs = stmt.execute();
  
    // Read each row and add it to the array we will return.
    var row_num = 1;
    while (rs.next())  {
      // Put each row in a variable of type JSON.
      row_as_json = {};
      driver_id = rs.getColumnValue(1);
      var subquery = "SELECT " + col_names_str + " FROM napp.core_extensions.eldhos_event WHERE organisation_id = '7703fd1a-c991-4505-98d4-d4b7b1c13da0' AND type = '1' AND record_status = '1' AND driver_id = '" + driver_id + "'";
      var cmd1_dict1 = {sqlText: subquery};
      var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1_dict1);
      var rs1 = stmt1.execute();
          
      // For each column in the row...
      while (rs1.next()) {
        row_as_json = {};
        for (var col_num = 0; col_num < COL_NAMES.length; col_num = col_num + 1) {
          var col_name = COL_NAMES[col_num];
          row_as_json[col_name] = rs1.getColumnValue(col_name.toUpperCase());
        }
        // Add the row to the array of rows.
        array_of_rows.push(row_as_json);
        ++row_num;
      }
    }
    // Put the array in a JSON variable (so it looks like a VARIANT to
    // Snowflake).  The key is "key1", and the value is the array that has
    // the rows we want.
    table_as_json = { "key1" : array_of_rows };

    // Return the rows to Snowflake, which expects a JSON-compatible VARIANT.
    return table_as_json;
  $$
  ;

CALL sp_return_table(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('GID', 'DRIVER_ID', 'EVENT_DATETIME', 'CMV_NUMBER', 'TYPE', 'CODE', 'RECORD_DATE', 'RECORD_TIME', 'ANNOTATION', 'VEHICLE_ODOMETER', 'CREATED', 'LAST_MODIFIED', 'ABSOLUTE_ODOMETER', 'ACCUMULATED_ODOMETER', 'EBOX_ODOMETER_METRES'));

SELECT VALUE:GID AS GID, VALUE:DRIVER_ID AS DRIVER_ID, VALUE:EVENT_DATETIME AS EVENT_DATETIME, VALUE:CMV_NUMBER AS CMV_NUMBER, VALUE:TYPE AS TYPE, VALUE:CODE AS CODE, VALUE:RECORD_DATE AS RECORD_DATE, VALUE:RECORD_TIME AS RECORD_TIME, VALUE:ANNOTATION AS ANNOTATION, VALUE:VEHICLE_ODOMETER AS VEHICLE_ODOMETER, VALUE:CREATED AS CREATED, VALUE:LAST_MODIFIED AS LAST_MODIFIED, VALUE:ABSOLUTE_ODOMETER AS ABSOLUTE_ODOMETER, VALUE:ACCUMULATED_ODOMETER AS ACCUMULATED_ODOMETER, VALUE:EBOX_ODOMETER_METRES AS EBOX_ODOMETER_METRES
FROM (SELECT $1:key1 FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))) AS res,
     LATERAL FLATTEN(input => res.$1);

       ORDER BY EVENT_DATETIME;
```

The above code should iterate through each distinct driver gid and populate the given gid in the larger query. The stored procedure is then called and subsequently the JSON is flatten to return the results in column format.

I'm getting the error `100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: document is too large, max size 16777216 bytes  SNOWFLAKE`. Any ideas how to minimise the json document :/ Is there a better way to do this. basically trying to loop through the gids in the larger query and storing each iteration and presenting it at the end for each gid. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your JSON is actually a single object then there's not much you can do, you'd have to re-think your approach. However, assuming your json is actually just repeating elements then make each element it's own JSON variant object and return a table from your SP rather than a column. This is logically the same as using the STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY file format option when trying to load large JSON files

Comment: I did try this using snowflakes web console however was not able to return a table, the table must be temporary. Can you provide a way to do this in snowflakes web console @NickW

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in snowflake's web console". Do you mean by changing your SP or do you mean something else - and, if so, what?

Comment: Yes by changing the SP @NickW

Comment: Sorry I meant I'm scripting on a Worksheet using Snowflakes Classic Console - I understand some functions cannot be used on it. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-using @NickW

Comment: I'm not sure that's relevant. As you want to process the result you probably should be using a Function rather than a SP. Change the line RETURNS VARIANT to RETURNS TABLE (column list). There are examples of a UDF returning a table here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions#basic-hello-world-examples

Comment: The logic of creating a single JSON structure for all of your records....why?  Does this have to be a JS SP?

Comment: No, I'm quite new to this and this was just something I came up with, open to suggestions @MikeWalton

Comment: My question was really focused on seeing if you'd be open to using a Python or Snowflake Scripting SP, instead.  You could then return the data in table format, rather than trying to squeeze it all into a single variant/json output.